# Firebase observeSingleEvent not triggered

Tags: ios, json, swift, database, firebase

I have a problem retrieving values from my DB. Whenever I run my method containing the "observeSingleEvent"-function it completely skips the method.

I have triple checked my path. I have one step, "user", that is not hard-coded and thought something might have gone wrong there. I hardcoded it - the block still is completely skipped.

Here is my function:

```
func retrieveAppState() -> String {
    var appState = ""

    let user = makeFirebaseString(with: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "User")!)

    let userInfoRef = ref.child("users").child(user).child("user-info")

    userInfoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let userInfo = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

        let state = userInfo["appState"] as! String

        print("App state is: \(state)")

        appState = state


    })

    return appState
}
```

I have tried numerous different variations of this for example the very common one with optional binding.

```
func retrieveAppState() -> String {
    var appState = ""

    let user = makeFirebaseString(with: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "User")!)

    let userInfoRef = ref.child("users").child(user).child("user-info")

    userInfoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let userInfo = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

         if let state = userInfo["appState"] as! String {
             appState = state
         }

    })

    return appState
}
```

Still the block is never executed. I have tried using the snapshot.exist() and nothing. It jumps from the observeSingleEvent line and directly to the return-statement. I know that the function is called and I know the ref is correct because it's the same I use when writing values to the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have posted my JSON structure below. These are just placeholders.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "Mach" : {
      "user-info" : {
        "appState" : "Training",
        "name" : "mattsh"
      }
    },
    "Mat-XXX@gmail-com" : {
      "user-info" : {
        "appState" : "Training",
        "name" : "Mat XXX"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** My rules in the database are now that everyone can read and write to the db i.e. no authentification is needed. Is there anything in iOS blocking this by default and so I might have to set something in the app to get permission for unsafe HTTP request??

Comment: Always use **`completionBlocks`** instead of function return `-> String` to tackle async calls that need to return something in a function. Is your print command working?

Comment: Can you come with an example? I created the function in my "firebase-connection" class to keep the code nicely separated and need to call from elsewhere. How do you suggest I retrieve the value from another class if the function does not have a return value? :=)

Comment: @Dravidian Thanks for leading me in the right direction. The block was executed, but because of the async call type it was executed much later and therefore appeared as skipped. My workaround was to set a UserDefault value and then adding an observer for this value in other views to update accordingly.